# Multiple Routes in node express backend

Tags: node.js, routes

I am new in node js and want to build an application in which they are multiple APIs and all are settled in routes folder but here is the problem when I tried to call the API in index.js(main file) its only take one route either userAPI or cleanerAPI.
As both APIs have different URL.

```
var mongoose = require ('mongoose');
var express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
const routerUser= require('./routes/userAPI')
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/Covid');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use('/',router);
app.listen(4000,function(){
    console.log("Server Running on 4000")
});
```

Comment: Could you also add the declaration of `userAPI` routes and `cleanerAPI` routes.

Comment: Also, where is `router` declared? What routes are declared using the statement `app.use('/',router);`

Comment: @DhruvShah That was by mistaken required('./routes/userAPI) .
and router is declared in below 
``````````````````````````
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router();
const user_Schema = require('../model/userModel')

router.post('/addUser',function(req,res){......}
module.exports = router;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this one also.

#### Main file(index.js or server.js)

```
const appRoutes = require('./Routes')
appRoutes(app)
```

#### Routes(index.js)

```
module.exports = app => {
 app.use("/user", require('./users'));
 app.use("/cleaner", require('./cleaner')); };
```

#### Routes(users.js)

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.route('/list')
 .post(function(req,res){......});

module.exports = router;
```